# is there other way to optimize JPG image without using webp?

Tags: image, jpeg, microsoft-edge, image-compression, webp

For a webp optimize the image, it is not supported even for IE Edge. So I wonder if webpack has other plugins than image-webpack-loader that can optimize jpg without webp?
https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader
https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-webp#options

Status (jaw-dropping for me to see that it is considered not planned at this moment....)
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webpimageformat/?q=webp

Answer (score 0):

WebP is currently supported by Chrome and Opera.

If you're seeking an alternative to JPEG for IE and Edge, you can consider JPEG XR:

https://jpeg.org/jpegxr/

Or stick with the JPEG image format and optimise it better. There are many optimisation libraries. Mozjpeg is perhaps the best:

https://github.com/mozilla/mozjpeg